# Meta "apple-itunes-app" doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, meta-tags

I've written an html page with the Apple meta to link at my app in the App Store:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=MY_APP_ID" app-argument="myschema:http://example.com">
```

The documentation 
(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)
says that with "app-argument" the app fires `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method and pass as url the app-argument.

The method doesn't been called.

The documentation of the methods say to use new method  `application:openURL:options:`, nothing change.

I read in other answer that this meta works only with the release app version (so isn't debuggable), so I put an hidden file log in the app and log at first line of method to be sure that the problem isn't my code in the method.

I tried in with ios11 and ios11.1

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation link you included specifically shows "app-argument" should be part of the value given to the `content` attribute and not an attribute itself. Notice where the quotation marks are:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: Is there a corresponding meta tag for Android?

Comment: @CaioMar there is `<meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.contoso">`